# How to move an apk file from root/data/app/ to storage/emulated/0 programmatically in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

These files will display a list of installed applications on your mobile and when an app is clicked it will create(or apk already exists) apk for that app in /data/app/.But I want to move that file to /storage/emulated/0 
I have tried using Environment,it is showing the same error as the former!

** In MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        File apkFile = new File(app.publicSourceDir);
        String dest=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"CodeViewer";
        String file=apkFile.getName();
        String src=Environment.getDataDirectory()+File.separator+"app"+File.separator+file;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,src+"   -  "+dest,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        moveFile(src,file,dest);
    }

    private void moveFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath) {

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {

            File dir = new File (outputPath); 
            if (!dir.exists())
            {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }


            in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);        
            out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            in = null;


            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;


//          new File(inputPath + inputFile).delete();  


        } 

        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
            Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I believe that `publicSourceDir` is a directory, not a file. Note that an app may consist of several APKs, not just one. Also note that you do not have access to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` on Android 10 (by default) and Android R and higher (for all apps). That restriction might also extend to `Environment.getDataDirectory()` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp " + source + " " + destination);
```

**To check if you have permissions** to copy that file as non-root user, open terminal or adb shell and type that command manually.